# In Octobercms item.viewBag.cssClass value with more than one classes use if statement with every class separately

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, octobercms-viewbag

In Octobercms Pages Plugin i can insert a CSS Class in menu item attributes. Then i can renter this value in the template using "item.viewBag.cssClass". So i can use:

```
{% if subitem.viewBag.cssClass == 'name' %}<li class="myname"></li>{% endif %}
```

The problem is when i want to use more than one classes in CSS class field.For example if i insert 2 classes in the field, name1 name2.Then i can use this:

```
{% if subitem.viewBag.cssClass == 'name1 name2' %}<li class="myname"></li>{% endif %}
```

But not this:

```
{% if subitem.viewBag.cssClass == 'name1' %}<li class="myname1"></li>{% endif %}
```

or this:

```
{% if subitem.viewBag.cssClass == 'name2' %}<li class="myname2"></li>{% endif %}
```

Is there a way on twig to identify a separate class inside of a value with 2 or more classes, so i can use if statement using any class i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Twig you can use the [Containment Operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator).

As an example, your last conditional would change to:

```
{% if 'name2' in subitem.viewBag.cssClass %}<li class="myname2"></li>{% endif %}
```

Comment: I missed that feature..This is exactly what i need. Thank you.

Comment: One relevant question.. Can i use Containment Operator with this logic:{% if 'first.class' in subitem.viewBag.cssClass %}<li class="{{first.class}}"></li>{% endif %} so i can display any class i use first, inside field?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but to break it down a bit... your if statement would check if the hardcoded string 'first.class' is in the subitem.viewBag.cssClass variable. Then, in your <li>, the {{ first.class }} code would assume that you have a variable in your twig scope with class as a attribute on that variable. I guess I'm not sure what you're going after here.

Comment: For example subitem.viewBag.cssClass = 'dropdown fadeIn'. If i want to use fadeIn class i have to use {% if 'fadeIn' in subitem.viewBag.cssClass %}<li class="myfadeIn"></li>{% endif %}. If class is fadeOut i have to use one other if statement e.t.c. But if i could use second.class i will be able to display the second class logic like this:{% if there is a second class in subitem.viewBag.cssClass %}{{ display second.class }}{% endif %}. I guess that is not possible..